# IPFS Config on windows 10

Tags: ipfs, windows, configuration

I'm trying to execute these commands on windows 10

```
./ipfs config --json API.HTTPHeaders.Access-Control-Allow-Origin '["*"]'
./ipfs config --json API.HTTPHeaders.Access-Control-Allow-Methods "[\"PUT\", \"POST\", \"GET\"]"
./ipfs config --json API.HTTPHeaders.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials '["true"]'
```

When  I try the first one on powershell, I get this error:

> Error: failed to unmarshal json. invalid character '*' looking for beginning of value

so I tried with this one just in case,

```
./ipfs config --json API.HTTPHeaders.Access-Control-Allow-Origin "[\"*\"]"
```

which gives me another error:

> Error: Unknown Command "API.HTTPHeaders.Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

What are the proper commands for above IPFS configs on windows 10 using powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using git bash on windows 10 solved the problem.